# Dynamically add project dependency depending on build path when project packaged as jar

Tags: java, maven

I have 2 projects `dependency-project`, `main`, `support`. Currently, `main` and `support` requires `dependency-project` in its build path.

We plan on adding `support` as another dependency for `main`. Is there a way to build a jar for `support`, but not include in it any dependency (from `dependency-project`) and when `support-jar` is already added into `main`, all dependencies of `support-jar` will be resolved via the classpath of `main` (since they both have `dependency-project` as dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as a compile-time scope. For example in `pom.xml` file for `support`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.something</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

And then in `pom.xml` for `main`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.something</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.something</groupId>
    <artifactId>support</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This should solve your purpose.

Comment: Would this be possible if ``main`` and ``dependency-project`` don't have maven configurations?

Comment: @Chad If they dont have `maven-configuration` then it depends on whatever build tool you are using. If nothing, then you can always do it manually (where you compile first with javac and then dont include jars while bundling)

Comment: But ``support`` will have ``project-dependency`` as a dependency. Can I build a jar for ``support`` without including ``project-dependency`` as a jar dependency, and maintaining it as a project dependency only at compile time?